# How to search a text from uitextview from uisearchbar that seach text will visible in UITextview only by yellow highlight color?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, uisearchbar

I want to search text of `UITextView` from `UISearchbar`.

My problem is that I want yellow highlight color where the search word found on `UITextView` after search.

Means if `UITextView` have the word "ego" then all the "ego" highlighted on `UITextView` after search.

Any Idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: Please explain the scenario bit more.

Comment: He wants to highlight his textfield in yellow if he doesn't find the word typed-in it. Best delegate method to use might be `searchBar:textDidChange:` @Tina, their is a method for UISearchBar named `setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:forState:` where you could set a yellow image for a state `UIControlStateNormal`. But you have to find a way to create your red image background

Answer (score 0):

You can't highlight the text in a `UITextView`.
 According to your question, [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) would be the solution, if you are targeting **iOS 6** or later. If you are targeting **iOS 5** also, then you can go for [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView)